# Python 3.6.8 - multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async() not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Its seems like apply_async is not working and nothing happens. Not sure whats wrong here. I am using MacOS catalina

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(sl):
    print(sl)
    time.sleep(sl)
    return sl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        for i in range(5,30,5):
            result = pool.apply_async(func=worker,args=(i,))
```

Comment: what IDE do you use? not all IDE's treat print statements from child processes correctly. Spyder for example just improved support in 5.2.0 you also over-write `result` and only keep the last one...

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code version: 1.61.2

Comment: try running your code from a terminal (or cmd on windows)

Comment: I would also recommend updating python to at least 3.9 if you want to really start to utilize `multiprocessing` (if your project allows it). There have been several important updates and fixes since 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `pool.apply_async` you are scheduling a task to be run. The return value from that call is a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` instance that you call method `get` on that will block until the task is completed and will return the return value from the worker function specified in the `apply_async` method call. But you have not called `get` (or `wait`) on any of these `AsyncResult` instances. Instead, you have let yourself *immediately* fall through to the end of the `with Pool(processes=3) as pool:` block and therein lies your problem.

The documentation is not very explicit. There is, however, this warning:

> Warning: `multiprocessing.pool` objects have internal resources that need to be properly managed (like any other resource) by using the pool as a context manager or by calling `close()` and `terminate()` manually. Failure to do this can lead to the process hanging on finalization.

You *are* using pool as a context manager as a result of the `with` statement and what actually happens is that at the completion of the `with` block there is a call to `pool.terminate()`. Thus all the processes in the pool are immediately terminated before they have a chance to run any of your submitted tasks.

Since you are not interested in the actual return values from `worker`, an alternative to saving the `AsyncResult` objects and calling `get` on them is to call `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` before exiting the `with` block, which will wait for all submitted tasks to complete:

> **`close()`**
> Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.

> **`join()`**
> Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call `close()` or `terminate()` before using `join()`.

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(sl):
    print(sl)
    time.sleep(sl)
    return sl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        for i in range(5,30,5):
            result = pool.apply_async(func=worker,args=(i,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
5
10
15
20
25
```